# Conflict between System.Web.Routing 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a kentico cms that i am upgrading to a new version (visual studio 2010). When i try to run the app, i get following error:

Error   102 The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' exists in both 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll' and 
'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll'
C:\PROJECTS\Upgrade\CmsSite\App_Code\Global.asax.cs 247 39  C:...\NrccuaCmsSite\

There upgrade files are with system.web.routing 3.5 and i have run auto updater that has put a reference to 3.5 also.

Both 4.0 and 3.5 do not show under bin folder. How can i get rid of one and solve above issue?

Answer (score 0):

Started a clean project since i got into some other problems also with this project.